# Returning string values from a column in my 2d array are being compressed into one string (opening Windows txt file on Mac os)

Tags: c++, string, file-io, text-files, fstream

I was given a  52 line text file and told to read the file, store values into an array, and return the values from that array on one row to emulate an album.

Lines from the text file "cd.txt":

```
Pantera
Cowboys From Hell
1990
Megadeath
Rust in Peace
1990
Anthrac
Worship Music
2011
```

Code to display the file content:

```
void displayCollection()
{
  string album[17][3], myArray[52];
  string line;
  int loop = 0, loop1 = 0, loop2 = 1, loop3 = 2;
  ifstream myfile("cd.txt");

  while (getline(myfile, line)){
    myArray[loop] = line;
    loop += 1;
  }
  myfile.close();

  cout << "\nArtist\t\t\tTitle\t\t\tYear\n" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++){
    album[i][0] = myArray[loop1];
    album[i][1] = myArray[loop2];
    album[i][2] = myArray[loop3];

    cout << album[i][0] << album[i][1] << album[i][2] << endl;

    loop1 += 3;
    loop2 += 3;
    loop3 += 3;
  }

}
```

How the format should print out :

```
Artist         Title                Year
Pantera        Cowboys From Hell    1990
Megadeath      Rust in Peace        1990
Anthrac        Worship Music        2011
```

Whats actually getting printed:

```
Artist         Title                Year
1990oys From Hell
1990 in Peace
2011hip Music
```

Comment: please provide some lines from "cd.txt"

Comment: I think you won't get far without a debugger here. You need to go line by line through your code and examine values of variables at each step to find out when they become corrupted (or maybe they are not corrupted and the issue is with printing only?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of the symptoms and your code, this can only be caused by the file encoding, and more precisely the [line break encoding](https://www.editpadpro.com/tricklinebreak.html):

- There are big chances that you have got a windows file, with the lines ending with a CR+LF, but you read it on a linux system, that parses for and end of line being LF only.
- The same could happen if you'd read a windows generated file using [binary mode instead of text mode](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes). But this is not the case in your code.

As a result, each of your string has a trailing CR character (i.e. '\r', that is `0x0D`).
Displaying it causes the cursor to move the begining of the line, so that the next string overwrites the previous string.  Of course when you go for `endl`, you jump to the next line.

Solution: get rid of the trailing 0x0D:

```
while (getline(myfile, line)){
    if (line.length()>0 && line[line.length()-1]=='\r') 
        line.pop_back(); 
    myArray[loop] = line; 
    loop += 1;
  }
```

Comment: Awesome! It was the file encoding and the thought of that being the problem went completely over my head. Also, thanks for the if statement

Comment: @DomingoHernandez I reinsure you: when I started to work across OSes, it took me a while to figure out, the first time it happened to me.  The kind of things that we don't forget  ;-)